# How to check Google map overlay type

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is that possible to check the type of a google map overlay.

```
var polygon = new G.Polygon();
var rectangle = new G.Rectangle();
var circle = new G.Circle();

var shape;
```

Now, my code will dynamically assign these overlay to `shape` variable.

But how can I detect or check the type of an overlay named `shape`? I can't find the solution using Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `instanceof`, but I'd advise against it. It's not part of the API and could break any time in the future.

It would be better to assign an attribute upon initialization.

```
var polygon = new G.Polygon();
polygon.type = 'polygon';

var rectangle = new G.Rectangle();
polygon.type = 'rectangle';

var circle = new G.Circle();
polygon.type = 'circle';

console.log(shape.type);
```

Comment: instanceof is not part of the API, but it is part of Javascript. It should work fine.

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider this: `function Marker() { return {} }; (new Marker) instanceof Marker; /* false */`

Comment: Maybe so that instanceof Marker; /* false */.... but you'd check if (shape instanceof google.maps.Marker) {// do something}.... That should work.

Comment: You missed my point. If the code behind the API changes in the way I demonstrated, `instanceof` would break.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the class via the Javascript instanceof operator:

```
var polygon = new G.Polygon();
var rectangle = new G.Rectangle();
var circle = new G.Circle();

var shape = selectShape(polygon, rectangle, circle); // your dynamic selection funktion
if (shape instanceof G.Polygon) {
    alert("found Polygon");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a function that returns the type of shape it was given. It supports circle and polygon but I'm sure someone can figure out how to add rectangle. It simply checks for unique properties of each.

```
function typeOfShape(shape){
    if(typeof shape.getPath === "function"){
        return "polygon";
    }else if(typeof shape.getRadius === "function"){
        return "circle";
    }else{
        return "unknown";
    }
}
```